# Can't run executable as libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll is missing

Tags: c, codeblocks

When I run my program within Code::Blocks it works fine. But when I build it and then click on the executable I get an error saying

> The program can't start because `libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll` is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.

I'm not to sure why that happens I did everything that all the tuts that I have watched to install Code::blocks have done.

Comment: Have you looked for libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll in your path? If it's not there, and it's not in the same directory as your program, you're likely to get this message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should copy `libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll` (it should be located somewhere similar to `C:\MinGW\bin` or `C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin`) into the same folder as the `.exe`.